# maven project in eclipse keeps normal package structure

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2e

I am trying to import a maven project (import->existing maven project) into eclipse and it is showing up in eclipse using the generic java project structure as opposed to the maven one. I have tried several versions of the m2e connection and all have the same problem. So for example instead of the following folders/packages/files I have:

```
src/
    main.java.my.package.name
          myfile.java
    test.java.my.package.name
          testfile.java
```

etc.

instead of the maven project structure

```
 src/main/java
         my.package.name
                myfile.java
```

etc.

Any assistance appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the sake of completeness:

This happens sometimes due to a race condition in eclipse.

As you already found out: if it happens, it happens only once, on initial import. So your way was almost correct:

- Remove all source paths
- do **not** add them manually
- instead, right-click on the project and select "Maven -> Update project" and accept the default settings. Now the source paths will be set correctly

Answer (score 1):

Woops, right after posting I was able to get it to work.

I had to go to project -> build path -> Source and remove the src/ folder and add the src/main/java, src/main/resources, etc. folders and it all works now.

Thanks for looking y'all!